# Импорт дампа базы данных в phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Привет всем!
Такая проблема: есть дамп sql-базы данных. Хочу импортировать её в phpMyAdmin, но при создании таблицы "ip" происходит ошибка:

```
SQL-запрос:

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Структура таблицы `ip`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ip` (

 `ip_id` INT( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
 `ip_ip` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `ip_kol` INT( 6 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `ip_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT  'дата последнего входа',
 `ip_agent` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'юзерагент браузера',
 `ip_kol_user` INT( 6 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'кол-во загрузки изображения браузером',
 `ip_flag_ban` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  '1-бан, 0-норм',
 `ip_flag_good` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  '1- проверил, это белый поисковик, 0 - не проверил, 2 - проверил - это обманщик'
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT =2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT =  'список ip по которым входят на сайт';

Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'ip_date'
```

Понятно что дело в `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, но я пробовал функцию "NOW()", такая же проблема. Кто подскажет, в чем может быть проблема.
Если это важно, то размер дампа 32МБ.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не воспроизводится. В отрыве от дампа если выполняете, прямо из вашего примера одну эту таблицу - таблица вставляется? Если да, то нужно начало дампа с комментариями задающими режим вставки.

Comment: @cheops Вы это имели ввиду? 


`SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;`

Comment: @cheops если вставлять эту одну таблицу, то таже ошибка.

Comment: посмотрите конфигурационный файл my.cnf, нет ли там директивы sql_mode, если есть - удалите и перезагрузите сервер.

Answer (score 1):

На запросы, выполняемые при разворачивании дампа может влиять режим выполнения `SQL_MODE`. Эта директива предназначена для обеспечения совместимости с другими базами данных. Поэтому некоторые возможности, которые характерны только для MySQL при использовании режимов `SQL_MODE` могут не поддерживаться.

Если вы не планируете использовать СУБД отличные от MySQL, лучше все убрать любые упоминания `SQL_MODE` из дампа и убрать директиву `sql_mode` из конфигурационного файла my.cnf (если там эта директива имеется).

Comment: Не помогает. Та же ошибка. Удалил директиву `SQL_MODE`, в файле my.ini директивы `sql_mode` нету.